# Remembering terminal states in OS X (like Fluid for the shell...)

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a few different things open in the terminal whenever I'm developing -- log tailing, Ruby console, plain shell in a certain directory, and so on.

How do I:

- start all those things at once, hopefully in the right position on the screen?
- make them distinct so I can switch to them with Quicksilver / Alt-Tab?

Fluid solved this problem with all of my web apps, so now I want to do it with my terminals.

---

And while we're on the topic, has anyone found a working solution for getting OS X to remember window positions on an external monitor? If I unplug it and plug it back in, I have to drag everything back to the same position (although at least Mercury Mover makes it possible to do it with the keyboard.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Terminal, and go into Preferences, then go into the settings tab, and create a new setting for each of your windows that you want.  Either give them all different colour schemes, or duplicate a colour scheme multiple times for them all to have the same settings.  Under the shell sub-tab, add "Run command" to be run at shell startup.  (This is the command that will `cd` to the directory you want, or `tail` a log).

Then initialise the windows as you want.  Then click Window in the main menu and select Save Windows as Group...

Answer (score 0):

In OSX Yosemite you can use (in Terminal) Window -> Save group. It will do all the work for you.